# creating textbox at runtime

Tags: asp.net

how to create textboxes at runtime on button click. As many time as the button is clicked and the value of textbox is to be passed to next page through session.

i have such code so far

```
int count=0;
 protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var i = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= count+1; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            form1.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.ID = "r" + count;
            txt.Text = txt.ID;
        }
     }
```

Here i want to give the ID to all the textbox that will be created at runtime.This code displays textbox only once when the button is clicked. But i want to display textbox everytime when the button is clicked.

If do this

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var i = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            form1.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.ID = "r" + count;
            txt.Text = txt.ID;
            count++;
        }
     }
```

there displays 5 textbox with id of textbox like ro,r1,r2,r3,r4.

please help me. I have been working on this for many days.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would look at putting an asp:repeater control on the page containing a textbox and changing it's data source (adding more rows to it) for each textbox you want added to the page.